# Instead of wiping out Covid-19

Tags: modal-verbs

Consider the third paragraph of ["What happens if a coronavirus vaccine is never developed? It has happened before"](https://edition.cnn.com/2020/05/03/health/coronavirus-vaccine-never-developed-intl/index.html?fbclid=IwAR3Weydu7a1YobF0mgHmp1_QI9-x-B6-Ii1u3PHv3ZkbkzwyCjoH-mYgY-8) (emphasis mine):

> Instead of wiping out Covid-19, societies **may** instead learn to live with it. Cities would slowly open and some freedoms will be returned, but on a short leash, if experts' recommendations are followed. Testing and physical tracing will become part of our lives in the short term, but in many countries, an abrupt instruction to self-isolate **could** come at any time. Treatments **may** be developed -- but outbreaks of the disease **could** still occur each year, and the global death toll would continue to tick upwards.

Does the *first* **may** suggest anything like **maybe will** (as in *it **may** rain tonight*) and the *second* **may** and the *two* **could**s suggest **maybe would** (as in conditional *maybe* sentences)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The first "*may*" suggests a **possibility**, just like your sentence "*It **may** rain tonight*."

> Instead of wiping out COVID-19, **it is possible that** societies learn to live with it...
>
> Instead of wiping out COVID-19, **there is a possibility that** societies learn to live with it...

The second "*may*" seems to me to suggest **contingency**. It suggests *possibility*, but that possibility is *diminished* compared to the possibility of what comes after. The sentence is targeting people who think that if a treatment for COVID-19 is developed, that means that the disease will go away. The article argues that there is a possibility that the disease could still come back, whether there is a treatment or not. This sentence essentially means

> **It is possible/likely that** a treatment will be developed, **but it is *also* possible/likely that** outbreaks of the disease will still occur...

Notice that  the sentence wants you to focus on the idea that "*outbreaks will still occur*," as opposed to "*a treatment will be developed*".

In terms of the word "*could*", in both cases it suggests possibility. The whole paragraph is one giant "possibility fest," if you will.

Comment: You say: **The first "may" suggests a possibility, just like your sentence "It may rain tonight."** 1) Does the two "could"s in the passage suggest the same meaning as the first "may"(as in "it may/could rain tonight")? 2) Could we replace "may" and "could", wherever they appear in the passage, with "can"?

Comment: @Mr.X 1) Yes: to me, the meaning is the same. 2) No: if you replaced _may_ with _can_, it would change the meaning of the sentence, and you can't replace _could_ with _can_ because _could_ is conditional and _can_ is not.